# Trying to use z-index to hide part of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my page: http://www.replyonline.co.uk/Brayborne/www/index.html

On the main nav if you click Services you see a dropdown appear. The nav class is `.nav nav-pills nav-stacked.`

I'd like the top part of this dropdown to appear underneath `navbar-wrapper` so the box-shadow I've set on `navbar-wrapper` shows on the dropdown giving it a layered effect as per the design below:-

[image]

Would anyone be able to offer any advice or CSS which I can use to achieve this? Also if it helps, the site is build using Bootstrap.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't use the z-index here because your dropdown is *inside* your `navbar-wrapper`. And everything inside an element is *on top of* that element. But you may trick your layout by applying a box-shadow inset on your dropdown and place right at the border of your navbar-wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index won't help you because your dropdown is *inside* your `navbar-wrapper` and will consequently always be on top of it.

**Try this:**

Remove the CSS arrow by removing `.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before`.

On your dropdown menu, change these styles:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  margin: 0;
  top: 74px;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Dropdown]

Change the box-shadow values to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but should get you going:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    z-index: -1;
}

#myCarousel {
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Working demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/EGmZ5/